# file_get_contens from remote url not working

Tags: php

i am trying to copy remote image file and reducing the size of image file and uploading to server but image file is created but it is not working .it gives error that image can not be displayed as it contains errors.

my code is this

```
<?php 

$url = 'http://www.indiancinemagallery.com/gallery/vaani-kapoor/Vaani-Kapoor-at-Radio-Mirchi-Stills-(9)9678.jpg';
$img = '/home/xxxxxxx/public_html/xyyyyyy/test.jpg';
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($url);
$fimg=imagejpeg($im, NULL, 60);

file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($fimg));

?>
```

Comment: what exactly is the error? copy paste as is.

Comment: Are you able to open it with any image viewer?

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL no it gives error that file contains error so cant be displayed

Comment: @VolkanUlukut it gives error that file contains error so cant be displayed

Comment: open it with a text editor. you'll probably see the real error there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read it from file by getting content, write it to file and read from file like;

```
<?php 

$url = 'http://www.indiancinemagallery.com/gallery/vaani-kapoor/Vaani-Kapoor-at-Radio-Mirchi-Stills-(9)9678.jpg';
$img = '/home/xxxxxxx/public_html/xyyyyyy/test.jpg';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
$fimg=imagejpeg($im, NULL, 60);


?>
```

Comment: if i am copying any image from remote url then that image is really loaded and that bandwidth is counted or not for remote/copying server

Comment: Bandwith on your server or remote?

Comment: in which server it will be counted or in both server. i think it should not be counted as it is happening server to server

Comment: It will be counted on remote server

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to save the image twice.
Your first try is incorrect, it should be

```
imagejpeg($im, $img, 60);
```

and don't do the `file_put_contents`

Comment: actually @xdazz answer is the better one performance wise, as no image is created inside the memory. But the image is saved 1:1 then, no quality changes or whatsoever possible. using imagejpeg allows that. Both solutions work fine, chose depending ion your needs.

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents` take a string as the parameter. `imagejpeg` just output image to browser or file, and return a boolean.

```
$url = 'http://www.indiancinemagallery.com/gallery/vaani-kapoor/Vaani-Kapoor-at-Radio-Mirchi-Stills-(9)9678.jpg';
$img = '/home/xxxxxxx/public_html/xyyyyyy/test.jpg';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```

Comment: i dont just want to put the image in server i want to reduce the size

Comment: @Priya See Musa's answer then.

Comment: @Priya You should do the image operation after download the image to your server.